# How to create class diagram in MS Visio for A4 page size?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-visio

I want to create a class diagram in MS Visio. I have set the page size and print setup to A4. I am using text size of 12pt. But the problem is I can't get all my classes inside the page in Visio. I tried to use bigger page sizes and bigger text size but then when I copy the drawing to MS Word the text is very very small.

Comment: Which version of Visio?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong. I had to change the page size of my drawing. I had tried it a few times before asking the question but it just wasn't working. Maybe there was another problem.

Here is how to do it:

So in the Design tab, choose Size and then select More Page Sizes. After that select the Page Size tab. Choose Pre-defined size and select Metric (ISO) A4.

Also, make sure that the Auto Size option that is right next to the Size option is not enabled. Otherwise it will add more and more pages to fit your drawing and you will need more than one A4 paper.